# Costs of items in Québec

Tags: québec, économie

How do I say "This item costs five dollars and twenty-five cents" in Québec French? Je connais les nombres mais je ne connais pas les mots justes.

Comment: This looks like a very simple sentence. What have you tried so far? What word(s) have you trouble translating?

Comment: Agreed with @jilliagre -- since this is your first question, please note that translation requests are more easily justified if you supply a couple of tries of your own to show your effort. :)

Comment: I would say: _ce truc coûte cinq dollars et vingt-cinq cents_. Replace _truc_ by proper word for what item in question.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of registers you can go for for "dollars" and "cents".

For dollars, you can say *dollars* or you can say *[piasses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piasse)*, which is a mispronunciation of the old *[piastre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piastre)*. The latter is a more casual register, but everyone understands it and you'll hear it a lot, especially from shoppers. Employees will tend to stick to *dollars*.

For cents, you can say *cents*, *cennes* or *sous*. The latter two are once again not formal, but very widely used, especially when combined with *piasse*, but they are used with *dollars* as well. Contrary to *piasse* though, there is not really any shopper/employee division in their usage.

So, some examples of things you could say are:

> Ceci coûte cinq dollars et vingt-cinq cents.
>   Ceci coûte cinq dollars et vingt-cinq cennes.
>   Ça coûte cinq dollars et vingt-cinq sous.
>   Ça coûte cinq piasses et vingt-cinq cennes.
>   Ça coûte cinq piasses et vingt-cinq sous.
>   C'est cinq piasses et quart.

It is also common to simply forgo dollars and cents entirely and imply them:

> Ça coûte cinq et vingt-cinq.

Comment: Ah oui! Les sous! C'est vrai, j'ai pas mal entendu ça. On peut aussi mélanger, non? _ca coûte cinq dollars vingt-cinq sous_ ...  J'ai un ami que j'ai entendu dire ça, peut-être pour m'éviter _piasse_ vu que je ne suis pas Québecois.

Comment: @Frank Oui, on peut mélanger, absolument!

Comment: On me suggère aussi: cinq piasses et vingt-cinq.

Comment: @Frank Ma liste ne se voulait pas exhaustive, mais si, ça se comprend aussi.